# Depth occlusion with depth texture OpenGL/GLSL (3.3/330)

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

My world is partitioned in an octree (tris are split automatically) and each chuck has its own index buffer (vbo is shared).  I have set up the FBO to write to a depth texture on a simple and minimal pre-pass, but I am having difficulty visualising the next step.

I was hoping to organise the chunks in the frustum (returned from the octree) from front to back, and then render it to the depth texture.  If no writing occurred then it can be assumed that the chuck is hidden.  However, I don't know if such a test is possible in opengl, because I have been led to believe that you can't read the depth texture whilst the FBO is bound.  Plus, I have no idea how such a comparison test would happen (can the FBO be used in this way?)

An alternative is to use the final depth texture for the final render (pass it to the fragment shader), and dismiss the fragments which is considered to be behind the value determined in the depth texture acquired from the pre-pass (early Z?).

I could settle for the second method, but would prefer to dismiss the chunks to minimize draw-calls and material binding.

I was hoping someone could shed some light on the issue, as I have searched for 'the best way' to do this but my knowledge of these methods and the FBO is relatively limited and I have only used FBOs for shadow mapping lights.

Sorry to be a nuisance - I know about hardware occlusion testing, but was hoping to implement a more general depth occlusion system which doesn't require 'waiting'.

EDIT:  Just a note, for the pre-pass I was only going to render a tight-fitting bounding box to start with.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking about. Many of the proposed algorithms you're talking about don't really make sense. For example, if you have the final depth buffer (aka: you did a depth pre-pass), why do you need the fragment shader to "dismiss the fragments..."? That will happen as a matter of course, simply by rendering the objects again.

Comment: Hi Nicol, I think I understand what you are saying.  The GFX card will automatically dismiss fragments that fails the depth test when it is interpolating in the fragment shader, right?  If this is the case then I don't even need to do a pre-pass???  However, what I am trying to figure out is depth occlusion with the returned chucks from the octree, in order to prevent binding them (inc. textures etc) in the final rendering pass.  Think of it like a BSP system but only with chunks of triangles and using the depth buffer to dismiss entire chunks before the second pass.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not looking for [OpenGL Occlusion Queries](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/occlusion_query.txt) then you probably want a **CPU** based solution.

What I recommend to you is a software rasterizer.
Render the occluders/occludees on the CPU instead of the GPU.
Example algorithm:

1. Rasterize all occluders' z-values into a buffer (for example walls).
2. For every occludee (for example furniture and other small objects) check for occlusion by rasterizing their bounding boxes into the same buffer (without writing to it).
3. If there were unoccluded pixels while rendering the occludee bounding box, render the occludee.

That's a solution that'll work on pretty much any hardware.

Here are two great presentations about how Guerilla implemented it in Killzone (render occluders on the CPU and check for occlusion by rasterizing occludee bounding boxes):
http://de.slideshare.net/guerrillagames/practical-occlusion-culling-on-ps3
http://de.slideshare.net/guerrillagames/practical-occlusion-culling-in-killzone-3

Here's how Crytek does it (read back and modify depth buffer of the previous frame and rasterize occludee bounding boxes on top of it):
http://de.slideshare.net/TiagoAlexSousa/secrets-of-cryengine-3-graphics-technology

And heres a presentation about Umbra 3 occlusion culling:
http://de.slideshare.net/Umbra3/visibility-optimization-for-games

There are also demonstrations by intel (also using a software rasterizer).

Anyway: There's no perfect solution to your problem. You'll have to decide on your own what works best for you.